# How to use delayed job in rails observer with faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, faraday

With the app I'm building, we're using trumpia to schedule and send sms, and email messages to our users. When they sign up, I'm using an observer to trigger the call to trumpia, and I'm using faraday to actually connect with the trumpia API. My problem is that these calls are taking a lot of time, and I need to put them into the background. I also have a smaller set of commands that I need to run immediately, so I can't just delay the whole after_create.

I'm thinking of using delayed_job to accomplish this, but I have no idea how to do it with something as convoluted as my code is. How can I do this? I think I need to put the Faraday calls into a method, but I don't know how. -- Thanks

Here's my observer. I've left out the code that isn't necessary.

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

def after_create(user)
   #This first part should not be delayed
     @user = user
     kevin = User.find(1)
     user.increment!(:renewcash, by = 5)
     body = "Hi " + @user.name.split(' ', 2).first + ", ..."
     kevin.send_message(@user, body, "First message", sanitize_text=true, attachment=nil)

   # This whole second part needs to be delayed.
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://api.trumpia.com') do |faraday|
      faraday.request  :multipart 
      faraday.response :logger                  
      faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  
    end

    trumpia_body = {:list_name => ... .... }.to_json

    response = conn.put do |req|
       req.url '/rest/v1/XXXXXXXXX/subscription'
       req.headers['X-Apikey'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
       req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
       req.body = trumpia_body
    end

    response2 = conn.get do |req2|
       req2.url '/rest/v1/XXXXXXXX/subscription?row_size=1'
       req2.headers['X-Apikey'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
       req2.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    end
 end
```

I'm using rails 3.2.8. But I haven't install delayed job yet, and I'm open to a different queing gem.